# How to calculate the total price automatically using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I created a form of ticket ordering. I have to calculate the total price of purchasing the adult and discount (child and senior) tickets.

Here is the html code.

```
<form action="">
        <p>Adult: $<span class="price-adult">52</span></p>
        <p>Discount (3 - 11 years old; 65 years old or above): $<span
                class="price-discount">23</span> </p>
        <label for="num-adult">Number of Visitor (Adult):</label>
        <input type="number" id="num-adult" name="num-adult" min="1" max="50" 
                value="1"><br><br>
        <label for="num-discount">Number of Visitor (Discount):</label>
        <input type="number" id="num-discount" name="num-discount" min="1" max="50" 
                value="1"><br><br>
        <p>Total Amount: $ <span class="total"></span> </p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Here is the Javascript code that I have written. I tried to write the adult version first so the discount ticket is not included in the JS code. Please help me find the problem.

```
    let numOfadult = document.getElementById("num-adult").value
    const priceOfAdult = document.getElementsByClassName("price-adult").value

    function getTotalPrice() {
       let total = numOfadult * priceOfAdult
       document.getElementsByClassName('total').textContent = total
}
getTotalPrice()
```

Comment: A line like `let numOfadult = document.getElementById("num-adult").value` will not extend into the future. That line runs exactly once, and it will store `"1"` in numOfadult at that time. To do what you want, you need to first use `const numOfadultInput = document.getElementById("num-adult")` then do `let numOfadult = numOfadultInput.value` *inside* the function that does the calculation. Next, you need to add onchange or oninput listeners to your <input>s so the total updates automatically.

Comment: Here's the fixed code: https://jsfiddle.net/uht8546k/ (getElementsByClassName returns a list, as the name implies, so you need to add [0] to get the first element, you also need to get .innerText of the <span>s, they don't have a .value, and I renamed the function displayTotalPrice, since it doesn't return anything, I'm also prepending the values with a `+` to turn them into numbers or the calculation will return `NaN`)

Comment: @ChrisG Thanks for help! I am trying to read and type it again.

Answer (score -1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   </head>
   <body>
      <form action="">
         <p>Adult: $<span class="price-adult" id="price-adult" >52</span></p>
         <p>Discount (3 - 11 years old; 65 years old or above): $<span
            class="price-discount">23</span> </p>
         <label for="num-adult">Number of Visitor (Adult):</label>
         <input type="number" id="num-adult" name="num-adult" min="1" max="50" 
            value="1" onkeyup="sum();"><br><br>
         <label for="num-discount">Number of Visitor (Discount):</label>
         <input type="number" id="num-discount" name="num-discount" min="1" max="50" 
            value="1"><br><br>
         <p>Total Amount: $ <span class="total" id="total"></span> </p>
         <input type="submit" value="Submit">
         <script>
            function sum() 
            {
            var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('num-adult').value;
            var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('price-adult').innerHTML;
            var result = parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue) * parseInt(txtSecondNumberValue);
            if (!isNaN(result)) 
            {
                      document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = result;
            }
            }
         </script>
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. You are missing the explanation for what you posted.